# в чем ошибка? (python 3.9.x) def newversion: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

в чем ошибка? (python 3.9.x)  def newversion:                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Может приложите код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а параметры функции кто будет задавать?

```
def newversion():
    # код функции
```

Comment: вы на 24 секунды раньше

Answer (score 2):

посде имени функции должны стоять круглые скобки

```
def newversion():
```